# Unexpected token end of file at position 0 error during I parse FileReader

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a little trouble that always happens when I first use my code and I do not understand why. I use a Watcher-service to control a folder. As soon as a new file (contains data in JSON) enters in this folder, I parse it to process it. From the first parsing I have an error Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0. Sometimes happens after too, but randomly I feel.

I already looking different way to do I did not find ...

This is an example of json file :

```
{"identifier":"004","note":null,"addresses":null,"msgType":"Alert","code":null,"references":null,"source":null,"sent":"2018-01-17T22:39:00-07:00","sender":"test","scope":"Public","restriction":null,"incidents":null,"status":"Actual","info":{"severity":"Severe","area":null,"audience":null,"expires":null,"resource":null,"certainty":"Likely","description":null,"language":null,"onset":null,"eventCode":null,"effective":null,"responseType":null,"senderName":"Los Angeles Police Dept - LAPD","urgency":"Immediate","web":null,"instruction":null,"contact":null,"parameter":{"valueName":"Beeldvorming","value":"<b>Time: 2019-09-07T15:44:54-00:00<\/b>  Sender: Fire DepartmentMessage: Hello007"},"category":"Rescue","event":"Child Abduction","headline":"Amber Alert in Los Angeles County"}}
```

This my Java code who parse this Json :

```
while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        System.out.println("Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
        if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
            String fileName = event.context().toString();
            try {
                String absolutePath = lcmsFolderPath + fileName;
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(absolutePath);
                // If unexpected token end of file at position 0
                // == parse used twice.
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser
                        .parse(fileReader);
                JSONObject infoJson = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("info");
                JSONObject parameterJson = (JSONObject) infoJson.get("parameter");
                String htmlValue = (String) parameterJson.get("value");
                String valueName = (String) parameterJson.get("valueName");
                fileReader.close();

                if (htmlValue != null) {
                    createLCMSDocument(valueName, htmlValue);
                }
            } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    key.reset();
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Most likely the file hasn't been saved fully and you're trying to read data which doesn't exist (yet). Are you writing directly to the directory, or moving a file there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm writing directly to the directory. Maybe a Thread.sleep should be enought ?

Comment: No the correct approach is to write the file fully in a temporary directory, then move the file to the processing directly. There's also a renaming technique which isn't applicable here. You don't want to sleep for nothing, and you don't want to sleep for too little. That's why `Thread.sleep()` is not a proper solution.

Comment: Ok, I see. So, I will try ! Thanks you